# Why is my function declaration wrapping to 2 lines?

Tags: phpstorm

I am using PHPStorm 7. When I write the following code,

```
public function ()
{

}
```

and then reformat it, it outputs the following format:

```
public
function ()
{

}
```

Why does the word 'function' wrap to a second line? I tried turning and off every setting in the PHP code style settings dialog with no success. Where can I turn that off?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is a setting called 'Wrap after modifier list' that puts the 'function' keyword on a new line. You probably have that checked.

As it's name suggests, it 'wraps' after the modifier list. Modifiers are keywords such as `public`/`protected`/`private`, `abstract`, `final`, `static` etc. So

```
final public static function bar()
```

becomes

```
final public static
function bar()
```

Note that classes are affected by this, too:

```
abstract class Foo
```

becomes

```
abstract
class Foo
```

The setting should be in the 'Wrapping and Braces' tab (under Settings > Code Style > PHP), in the bottom of the list. Unchecking it should solve your problems.

Comment: I had to toggle this on and off again to get the effect I was desiring.

Answer (score 1):

You are using defining public function() outside class which doesn't have any meaning

```
Before Formatting :
Class test{
public function uder(){

   }
}
public function outside(){
}
```

Now Public keyword has no meaning hence on formatting phpStorm wrap function in newline

```
Class test{
public function uder(){

   }
}

public 
function outside(){

}
```